# Vaadin - Multiple buttons instance - different click listener action

Tags: java, vaadin

I have problem with displaying multiple panels which contain for example a label and a button. I want to listen for button click and display label value from the panel. 
Code looks something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5;i++){
 Panel p = new Panel("panel "+i);
 Label l = new Label("label "+ i);
 p.addComponent(l);
 Button show = new Button("Show Label in subWindow", new Button.ClickListener() {
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    Window sub = new Window("testing "+label);
                    getMainWindow().addWindow(sub);
                }
    });
}
```

I know that this code on every button remember the last value of label. 
How can i in loop for every pass bind specific button to display value of specific label?
I am trying to achive something like PageableListView control in wicket.

I hope you'll understand my question!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you subclass the Button and make Label instance (Panel instance or any other instance) part of its state?

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    private Label label;

    public MyButton (String title, Label l) {
        super(...);
        this.label = l;
        addListener(...);
    }
}
```

In the other word, if you need a button to have a link to some object -- create it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that Vaadin has method setData and getData for class Button. So, its possible to do button.setData(product) and again in listener do event.getButton().getData()

Comment: You are welcome. Solution with AbstractComponent.setData(Object data) is not that clear and it also violates OOP approach. Is it so straightforward to call label data and attache it as Object to button?